# How to debug a non-working AJAX-based HighChart?

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I came across **HighChart**. I have followed some of the tutorials, but unfortunately I am not able to execute. The page is loading blank. I have added all the required scripts.

Here is the following code:

### **data.php**

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("demo", $con);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT month, wordpress, codeigniter, highcharts FROM project_requests");

$category = array();
$category['name'] = 'Month';

$series1 = array();
$series1['name'] = 'Wordpress';

$series2 = array();
$series2['name'] = 'CodeIgniter';

$series3 = array();
$series3['name'] = 'Highcharts';


while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $category['data'][] = $r['month'];
    $series1['data'][] = $r['wordpress'];
    $series2['data'][] = $r['codeigniter'];
    $series3['data'][] = $r['highcharts'];   
}

$result = array();
array_push($result,$category);
array_push($result,$series1);
array_push($result,$series2);
array_push($result,$series3);

print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);              

    ?>
```

### **index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=html>
    "text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Bar chart with data from MySQL using Highcharts</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


            $(document).ready(function() {


            var url = "http://localhost/test/example9/data.php";

            $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                options.series[0] = json[1] ;
                options.series[1] = json[2] ;
                options.series[2] = json[3] ;

                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);



            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Project Requests',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Requests'
                    },
                    labels: {
                        overflow: 'justify'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }, 
                plotOptions: {
                    bar: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{}]
            }



            });
        });
        </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-json.googlecode.com/files/jquery.json-2.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jugal.me/js/jugalsLib.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.src.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.src.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have traced the AJAX response rendered by `data.php` and have found the following text in my browser's Network tab:

### **Browser Network Tab--Response**

```js
<br />

<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-deprecated' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\test\example9\data.php on line <i>2</i></th></tr>

<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>

<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>

<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0000</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>246984</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\test\example9\data.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\data.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>

<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0000</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>247272</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect' target='_new'>mysql_connect</a>
(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\test\example9\data.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\data.php<b>:</b>2</td></tr>
</table></font>
[{"name":"Month","data":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]},{"name":"Wordpress","data":[4,5,6,2,5,7,2,1,6,7,3,4]},{"name":"CodeIgniter","data":[5,2,3,6,7,1,2,6,6,4,6,3]},{"name":"Highcharts","data":[7,8,9,6,7,10,9,7,6,9,8,4]}]
```

Comment: Would you be more specific about what is not working? Should the chart load the data via AJAX/JSON? If so, have you checked your browser's network tab to examine the request and the response? Do you get any JS errors in your browser's JS console?

Comment: I have created and configured the database after that I have encoded the database details to JSON format in **data.php**. Now in **index.php** I need to call the **data.php** and I need to display the JSON data into the **Highchart**. I have executed the code in server but it is loading as blank page or no data. Could you please help me out. Once again thanks for the response.

Comment: Did you check your browser's network tab and JavaScript console?

Comment: yes, I have checked the browsers. In **Console** no data is displaying. But in the Network Tab, the JS files are listed out with status 200 and **jquery.min.js** as status 304

Comment: Those are your JavaScript files loading. However, I think there should be an additional network operation to fetch the data in `data.php` - check that.

Comment: I have removed the angle brackets.  But I am not able to go step further. Could you help me out in pointing the mistakes, if not can you please provide me the code, so that I can self correct my code after understanding

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay. I have checked the Network Tab, and I found that the **data.php** is not listed. Is there any error regarding this...???

Comment: I have checked in the Network console again. I noticed that the data.php is loading

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. `data.php` is an AJAX operation - what is the request URL (including query string parameters) and response? You will need your network tab for this. Please delete your last two comments.

Comment: I am sorry but  I couldn't get the meaning of it. In my chrome browser, I could see in the Network tab, that some .js files are loading as well as other files.

Comment: In your Network tab, click the `data.php` line so you can examine the request (you _have_ said it is in there). Then take a screenshot of the "Headers" sub-tab so we can see the Request URL. Then take a screenshot of the "Response" sub-tab so we can see the response to this request. You may need to reload your website with the Network tab open, in order to populate it.

Comment: Please find the snapshot by clicking on the image URL:  Headers:  ** http://s32.postimg.org/k6rxv019x/Headers_1.png**    Response:: **http://s32.postimg.org/509hkylx1/Response_2.png **

Comment: OK, see line 3 of the response? It has an error in it, and it has dumped a bunch of HTML inside your JSON output, which makes it unparseable by your JavaScript. What is that error? It is off-screen, so I cannot read it. It starts with the word "Deprecated". Please paste this whole response **in your question** formatted in a code block so we can read it properly.

Comment: I will add a fuller answer when I can, but for the time being try adding `error_reporting(0);` at the top of your `data.php` script. I will later explain why this is not an ideal fix, but it will get things working for now.

Comment: okk. Thanks for your response. I am looking ahead for your answer.

Comment: Please try it first, so I can see if I am on the right lines.

Comment: I have tried the way you have explained. But in the console of the browser window, only the URL of the local host is displaying. for example **http://localhost/test/example9/data.php**

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You need to check that the contents of the `data.php` AJAX operation no longer contains an error, and _only_ contains the string that begins `[{"name":"Month","data":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May",`...

Comment: Yes I understand that. I think I can't think beyond this. I have tried all my possible efforts to make the chart appear. I don't know what is the next step to be done.

Comment: Would you show us the new contents of the Response subtab of the Network tab in your browser console?

Comment: The response is as follows: In browser console, the following error is shown in the console: **http://s32.postimg.org/nmg6uuk5x/Capture_20.png**   and  **http://s32.postimg.org/57k43tg9h/Capture_21.png**

In network tab: **http://s32.postimg.org/t92y503h1/Capture_22.png**

Comment: I figured out that there is an error which is displaying i the console, but  I am not able to identify what exactly about it is..??

Comment: How are you getting on with this?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be in a hurry with the cut'n'paste.

### I encourage you to walk through your code line by line and find out what it does.

Only then will you learn. I can help you some on the way:

Starting with **index.php**
Dharmesh Goswami has already pointed out the incomplete line with `"text/html; charset=utf-8">`. Underneath that line you have an open script tag. It's missing `>`

If you take a look at your JavaScript, at the first six lines underneath `$.getJSON(url, function(json) {`:

```
 options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
 options.series[0] = json[1] ;
 options.series[1] = json[2] ;
 options.series[2] = json[3] ;

 var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

 var options = {
 ...
```

What is going on here? You are changing the object `options` four times before you create it at `var options = {`. Before that at `var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);` you are initializing HighChart with the settings inside of `options`. Before you create it!

In the JS you need to start with the `var options = {`, *then* you can change the xAxis and series and *then* you may initialize HighCharts with `var chart =...`.

As for the **data.php** I suggest you open the url for it and make sure it prints out valid json. And that the json is in a format that HighChart expect.

Here is an official fiddle showing ajax loaded data: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-ajax/

I wish you good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Rene Neim. I will definitely work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this below code for **index.php**

I have noticed that your `$(document).ready()` function is not called so I have added js files on top and also removing below line which is not completed.

> "text/html; charset=utf-8">

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=html>
        <title>Bar chart with data from MySQL using Highcharts</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-json.googlecode.com/files/jquery.json-2.2.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jugal.me/js/jugalsLib.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.src.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.src.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var url = "http://localhost/test/example9/data.php";

                $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
                    options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                    options.series[0] = json[1] ;
                    options.series[1] = json[2] ;
                    options.series[2] = json[3] ;

                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);



                    var options = {
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'container',
                            type: 'bar'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Project Requests',
                            x: -20 //center
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: '',
                            x: -20
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: []
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            title: {
                                text: 'Requests'
                            },
                            labels: {
                                overflow: 'justify'
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                    this.x +': '+ this.y;
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {
                            layout: 'vertical',
                            align: 'right',
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            x: -10,
                            y: 100,
                            borderWidth: 0
                        }, 
                        plotOptions: {
                            bar: {
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{}]
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and I respect your fast response. I have copied the above edited code given by you. But when I tried to execute in the server it is loading as a blank page. Actually I am new in PHP and a beginner. Could you please help me out in pointing out my mistake. So that I can rectify the code. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Run this code into your browser and check JS error into inspect element(F12 key). It will help you to find an error.

Comment: I tried to run this code. But I see no error in the console. Infact no data is displayed in the console. I checked the network tabs and the list of JS files are shown. I am not able to figure it out, how to take a decision. If you have any highchart sample code that is running dynamic code, then that can help me out in pointing out my mistakes where  I have done in the code.

Comment: Check this URL for dynamic data. : http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-from-a-database

Answer (score 0):

You have fixed one problem, which is that your AJAX JSON response was invalid, because it contained PHP warnings that made it unparseable.

Next, your JavaScript doesn't work. This code here:

```
options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
options.series[0] = json[1] ;
options.series[1] = json[2] ;
options.series[2] = json[3] ;

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

This should go after you have defined `options`, so move it after this:

```
var options = {
    ...
}
```

The reason for this is that you're accessing something that does not exist.

Also, the above options needs a semi-colon, so change it to this:

```
var options = {
    ...
};
```